# Python request return timeout, but the remote handle the request

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, request, uvicorn

I am trying to make a simple python code to request a uvicorn WSGI but it returns timeout all time.
In the browser or cURL I get response after ~2s, in Python, if I don't specify a timeout in request function, it will load forever.

The strange things is, python sends the request, returns timeout after long while but the remote handles the request and works in time !

this is the python code:

```
print("pass1",selected_server[0])
print("http://"+selected_server[0]+":8000/create/site/"+str(site)+"/"+str(user))
try:
    x = requests.get("http://"+selected_server[0]+":8000/create/site/"+str(site)+"/"+str(user))
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)
    x = None
    return 'error'
```

the URL definitly work outside python

in python error :

```
requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPConnectionPool(host='10.0.1.72', port=8000): Read timed out. (read timeout=20)
```

if you have some clue on this it will be great <3

EDIT : i tried to make an `os.popen("curl <url>")` inside the python, this not work, it load forever

but on the server, outside the python,  the same command work

Comment: A common requirement is a User-Agent. Try passing something meaningful in your HTTP headers

Comment: Hello, i add the user agent header, and this is not working,
but i found something strange 

on the remote server, if everything is ok, i make some things and i return a json with success information
if i cannot do the thing, i return an error json

the python request work with an error json (http/200) but not with the success json :c